# Impedir múltiplos envios com jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, funções, eventos

Fala pessoal, eu tenho uma table com diversos usuários, cada linha possui um Button para excluir aquele determinado registro, tenho o seguindo código:

```
$('body').on('click', 'button[name="btn-delete[]"]', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var action = $(this).data("function");
        var nameType = $(this).data("name");
        var codigo = $(this).val();
        var Name = $('.user-name-' + codigo).html();
        var element = $(this).parent().parent().parent();

        $('.header-modal-box h4').text('Deletar');
        $('.row-f label').text('Deseja remover o ' + nameType + ' ' + Name + '?');

        Modal();

        $('#btn-true').click(function () {
            if ($('.trigger_notify').length) {
                $('.trigger_notify').remove();
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: '_models/Data.php?action=' + action,
                method: 'POST',
                data: {codigo: codigo},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.erro === true) {
                        trigger(data.notify);
                        element.remove();
                    } else {
                        trigger(data.notify);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

Ao clicar no `button btn-delete`, apresento um modal com dois ancora, um com o confirma remoção, no caso (`#btn-true`), e um para cancelar(`#cancelar`) e fecha o modal.

Quando eu clico no `#btn-true` ele manda tranquilamente minha requisição, porem quando vou em um segundo registro, ele manda 2 requisições, a primeira e a segunda, e me aparece 2 notificações, resolvi esse problema com o `stopImmediatePropagation();`, porém, o `element.remove()`; para de funcionar, será se tem como eu reiniciar esse evento, pra ele não repetir com os mesmos dados do evento anterior? alguém aí pra da um help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode manter seu código exatamente como está na pergunta, apenas mudando o evento do click no botão `#btn-true` para evitar múltiplas requisições usando o método **[.one](http://api.jquery.com/one/)** do jQuery. Esse método faz com que o evento seja executado apenas 1 vez quando um botão `btn-delete[]` for clicado.

Basta alterar de:

```
$('#btn-true').click(function () {
```

Para:

```
$('#btn-true').one("click", function () {
```

Isso é mais vantajoso porque evita ter que criar variáveis globais como informou a primeira resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Seu codigo está mal  estrtuturado 
Você está definindo toda vez que o  seu  "body"  ouver um click  ele vai  adicionar  um EventListener para seu botão  $("#btn-true")
ou seja se você excutar ação 3 vezes ele irá adicionar 3 eventos no  mesmo  botão e assim por diante.

você tem  duas  opições para contornar esse problema o primeiro é simplesmente trocar o  trigger click  do botão inserindo apenas  o `<button id="btn-true" click="NomeDafuncao()">` ou alterar seu codigo a cima por algo como  isso.

```
<script>
var codigo = null;
var action = null;

$('document').ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click', 'button[name="btn-delete[]"]', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            action = $(this).data("function");
            var nameType = $(this).data("name");
            codigo = $(this).val();
            var Name = $('.user-name-' + codigo).html();
            var element = $(this).parent().parent().parent();

            $('.header-modal-box h4').text('Deletar');
            $('.row-f label').text('Deseja remover o ' + nameType + ' ' + Name + '?');

            Modal();
    });
    $('#btn-true').click(function () {
        if ($('.trigger_notify').length) {
            $('.trigger_notify').remove();
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: '_models/Data.php?action=' + action,
            method: 'POST',
            data: {codigo: codigo},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.erro === true) {
                    trigger(data.notify);
                    element.remove();
                } else {
                    trigger(data.notify);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Prefeito, funcionou!!! Tive que por a variável element para fora da função também.

Comment: Excelente :), que bom  q funcionou